# TLS client does not drop connection even when there are no suitable ciphersuites in the server ciphersuite list during handshake

Tags: tls, protocols, ciphers

I have two Windows systems, and I want to establish an encrypted TCP/IP communication between them. Specifically TLS 1.2 or TLS 1.3.
I have configured in both systems the list of allowed ciphersuites:

1. Win+R -> gpedit.msc which opens Local Group Policy Editor.
2. Local Computer Policty -> Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Network -> SSL Configuration Settings -> SSL Cipher Suite Order.
3. Set to Enabled
4. Under Options -> SSL Cipher Suites, I saved the list of cipher suites that I want for each of both systems.

Now this is the outcome of my tests:

- **Default list**: while they are different lists, they have some ciphersuites in common, so the connection is established.
- **Reduced list**: I made sure to remove the ciphersuite used in the previous test and some others, but there are still some ciphersuites in common -> connection established, and I can see that a different ciphersuite was used than before.
- **Custom lists**: different list for each system and they do not have any ciphersuite in common -> the connection is still established!

Why is the connection not dropped? Isn't the client supposed to drop connection when it finds out that none of the ciphersuites suggested by the server during the handshake is listed in its own ciphersuites list?

I don't understand if I am missing any additional configuration, or I am not setting the ciphersuites in the right place. Is there a "fallback" list that the client/server systems check when they don't find any suitable ciphersuite in the list under Local Group Policy Editor? I just want to completely prevent connections with ciphersuites other than a specific list under my control.

Comment: Unfortunately none of this can be reproduced with the details privided. It is not clear if the unknown client and server even use the settings from the group policy.  Also, the server will close the connection (maybe after an alert) if no shared cipher is offered by the client, not the other way around.

Comment: Server doesn't suggest ciphersuites: the client sends out a list of supported ciphersuites in ClientHello and the server chooses one it supports, too, and prefers over the others. No "backup lists" nor second rounds during the same handshake.

Comment: Ok it is clear to me now that it is the server who is supposed to close the connection. It is clear that it is using those settings since in test #2 a different ciphersuite was used (without changing client's ciphersuit list, only server's). So by backup I did not mean during negotiation, I meant if the handshake could be executed with an already built list that is a combination of the aforementioned policy settings + another list from another setting/configuration of Windows. Maybe user specific policies, although I did not find those for SLL ciphersuites.